# convenient way to reindex one level of a multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

consider the `pd.Series` `s` and `pd.MultiIndex` `idx`

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('AB'), [1, 3], list('XY')],
                                 names=['one', 'two', 'three'])
s = pd.Series(np.arange(8), idx)
s

one  two  three
A    1    X        0
          Y        1
     3    X        2
          Y        3
B    1    X        4
          Y        5
     3    X        6
          Y        7
dtype: int32
```

I want to `reindex` on `level='two'` with `np.arange(4)`
I can do it with:

```
s.unstack([0, 2]).reindex(np.arange(4), fill_value=0).stack().unstack([0, 1])

one  two  three
A    0    X        0
          Y        0
     1    X        0
          Y        1
     2    X        0
          Y        0
     3    X        2
          Y        3
B    0    X        0
          Y        0
     1    X        4
          Y        5
     2    X        0
          Y        0
     3    X        6
          Y        7
dtype: int32
```

But I'm looking for something more direct if it exists.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately if need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `MultiIndex`, need all levels:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('AB'), np.arange(4), list('XY')],
                                 names=['one', 'two', 'three'])

print (s.reindex(mux, fill_value=0))
one  two  three
A    0    X        0
          Y        0
     1    X        0
          Y        1
     2    X        0
          Y        0
     3    X        2
          Y        3
B    0    X        0
          Y        0
     1    X        4
          Y        5
     2    X        0
          Y        0
     3    X        6
          Y        7
dtype: int32
```

EDIT by comment:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 1, 'X'), ('B', 3, 'Y')],
                                 names=['one', 'two', 'three'])
s = pd.Series([5,6], idx)
print (s)
one  two  three
A    1    X        5
B    3    Y        6
dtype: int64

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 0, 'X'), ('A', 1, 'X'), 
                                 ('A', 2, 'X'), ('A', 3, 'X'), 
                                 ('B', 0, 'Y'), ('B', 1, 'Y'), 
                                 ('B', 2, 'Y'), ('B', 3, 'Y')],
                                 names=['one', 'two', 'three'])

print (s.reindex(mux, fill_value=0))
one  two  three
A    0    X        0
     1    X        5
     2    X        0
     3    X        0
B    0    Y        0
     1    Y        0
     2    Y        0
     3    Y        6
dtype: int64
```

---

***Direct Solution***

```
new_lvl = np.arange(4)
mux = [(a, b, c) for b in new_lvl for a, c in s.reset_index('two').index.unique()]
s.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).sort_index()

one  two  three
A    0    X        0
          Y        0
     1    X        0
          Y        1
     2    X        0
          Y        0
     3    X        2
          Y        3
B    0    X        0
          Y        0
     1    X        4
          Y        5
     2    X        0
          Y        0
     3    X        6
          Y        7
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I was thinking.  However, I can't use `from_product` generically on any `MultiIndex`.  For example, If the original index was `[('A', 1, 'X'), ('B', 3, 'Y')]`, I'd expect a `reindex` on `level='two'` would return `[('A', 0, 'X'), ('A', 1, 'X'), ('A', 2, 'X'), ('A', 3, 'X'), ('B', 0, 'Y'), ('B', 1, 'Y'), ('B', 2, 'Y'), ('B', 3, 'Y')]`

Comment: You are right, you can use `from_product` generally. You need only create new index some way and then reindex. Maybe `from_tuples`.

Comment: And then more complicated is creating tuples - maybe list comprehension can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the help.